# Jquery - Input focus() through parent and find nested element-class

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having this html. How can I with JQuery get the input-field with `id="studio123"` to be focused when click on the `<a class="mm-subopen" href="#clickMe"></a>`

```
<li class="img no-arrow join">
        <span class="user-wrapper">
            <a class="mm-subopen" href="#clickMe"></a>
        </span>
        <ul class="chat-messages" id="studio">
            <div class="chat-input">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studio123" placeholder="Type your message" />
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I was thinking of something like:

```
$('.mm-subopen').click(function () {
    //find this.class parent, parent (witch would be:  <li class="img no-arrow join">)
    //and then trough: <li class="img no-arrow join"> find the input in same scope and get it focused
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the link

```
<a class="mm-subopen" href="#clickMe"></a>
```

with label:

```
<label class="mm-subopen" for="studio123"></label>
```

And no javascript is needed. Or if you do need javascript try this:

```
$('.mm-subopen').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('input').focus();
});
```

Comment: I need to do it in js, because `href="#clickMe"` is used in many other parts of my code. Iv'e tried your js solution but it doesn't work. My  `<a class="mm-subopen" href="#clickMe"></a>` tag is built up dynamiclly when the document is loaded. Can that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, it can be an issue. Try this `$(document).on('click', '.mm-subopen', function () { $(this).closest('li').find('input').focus(); });`.

Comment: Strange, still doesn't work. I thought the last one you sent would fix it. Do you know what else can be the issue here? any suggestions?

Comment: Hm, not sure. Can you replicate the issue in fiddle?

Comment: By the way `.chat-input` must be `li` elements, not `div`.

Comment: made a simple fiddle and it works, so I think some of my other scripts in the code meesing this up. So I will look into that first. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

This is what your after i think

```
$('.mm-subopen').click(function () {
    $(this).parents("li").find(":input").focus();
});
```

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/4nodpom2/)